# Limit Return of SQL Query against Active Direct groups to specific Organisation Unit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory, openquery

I have a query to get all the groups that an AD person is in; but I have not been able to limit the results to only chosen Organisation Units, which I would like to do. Here is the query I have:

```
-- Test Variable --
DECLARE @Username NVARCHAR(254) = 'ABC'


DECLARE
     @DomainController  NVARCHAR(50)    = N'DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM'
    ,@Fields            NVARCHAR(256)   = N'ADsPath,cn'
    ,@ParamDefn         NVARCHAR(50)    = N'@PathOut NVARCHAR(1024) OUTPUT'

DECLARE
     @SQL   NVARCHAR(4000)
    ,@Path  NVARCHAR(1024)

SET @SQL =
'SELECT @PathOut = distinguishedName
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, ''
SELECT distinguishedName
FROM ''''LDAP://' + @DomainController + '''''
WHERE 
    objectClass = ''''user''''
AND sAMAccountName = ''''' + @Username + ''''''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefn, @PathOut = @Path OUTPUT

SET @SQL =
'SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, ''<LDAP://' + @DomainController + '>;(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' + @Path +'));' + @Fields + ';subtree'')'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

This returns all the groups of which `@Username` is a member and it's great. However, the results come back with the `ADsPath` column looking something like this:

```
LDAP://CN=Group1,OU=Role Groups,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
LDAP://CN=Group2,OU=Application Groups,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
LDAP://CN=Group3,OU=Role Groups,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
LDAP://CN=Group4,OU=File System Groups,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM
```

My question is this: how can I change my query so that (for instance) only groups where `OU=Role Groups` are returned?

The only way I can see to succeed at the moment is to examine the contents of the `ADsPath` after the event, using string functions and I do not want to go that way if I can avoid it, as it seems inefficient to get all groups and then get a subset of that result (not to mention the nastiness of the solution in other ways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but the most straightforward way to limit a query to a specific OU to add another filter to the ADSI query.

If you want to use [LDAP dialect for ADSI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746385(v=vs.85).aspx), you can add, for example, `(distinguishedName=*,OU=Role Groups,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM)` to your ADSI filter.

If you want to use [SQL dialect for ADSI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746494(v=vs.85).aspx), you can add `AND distinguishedName = '*,OU=Role Groups,OU=Groups,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM'` to your WHERE clause for the ADSI query.

Comment: I cannot get that to return any results (possibly related to this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c73fd3e-b09b-4a6f-8110-2f58680aaf6c/adsi-cant-search-by-distinguishedname-attribute?forum=ITCG ?) But I have taken your advice and added a WHERE clause  to the second query to give: `SET @SQL =
'SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY (ADSI, ''<LDAP://DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM>;(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=' + @Path +'));' + @Fields + ';subtree'')
WHERE ADsPath LIKE ''%,ou=Role Groups,ou=Groups,dc=DOMAIN,dc=COM'''` This works - thanks!